# how much is the central writevalue string length limit

Tags: core-bluetooth

How much is the `Central` `writeValue` data size limit,
I try send this string

`PeripheralModeTest - Demonstrated how to communicate with other iOS Devices via CBPeripheralManager.`

When I receive the data , Is divided into three string points three times.

If I send the string length of more than 180, can't send out.

Comment: Hi @Timothy can you please tell me how to send the data from iOS app to Non iOS device?